# Add multiple style properties to a single theme property with Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm using [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for a new project, and want to use the theming features of the library. I'm struggling to figure out if there is a good or best practice way of adding multiple style properties to one object (i.e., create a kind of inheritance). What is want is:

```
// in the theme, define a group of styles for a given component
// e.g. all fonts have a font-family, weight, size, etc
const theme = {
  fonts: {
    font-family: ...,
    font-weight: ...,
    font-size: ...,
  }
}

// then in my styled component,
// define the multi-line theme, along with component specific styles
// or even override the theme styles
const Header = styled.span`
  ${props => props.theme.fonts};
  text-decoration: underline;
  ...
`;
```

Right now, it's only apparent to me that you would need to pass the theme property to each style on the component. Is there a pattern that can help reduce some of the repeated code seen in my above example?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to define the theme styles in a separate files, for example

- MyComponent

  - index.js
  - styles.js //<-- Custom styles for component
- theme

  - spacing.js // <-- Common styles for all components
  - colors.js
  - fonts.js

Inside `spacing.js` I would have something like this:

```
const verticalPaddingSmall = {
  paddingTop: 5,
  paddingBottom: 5,
};

const verticalPaddingMedium = {
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10,
};

export default function spacing(size, direction, isPadding) {
  // some logic to return the correct object based on the params,
  // screen size (tablets vs phones), etc...
  return verticalPaddingSmall;
}
```

Obviously, that code is automatically generated based on some configurations I define for different screen sizes and so on, but the end result is something similar to that.

Then in my custom component I import the common styles, apply them to the styles and overwrite if needed it, something like this on `styles.js`:

```
import spacing from 'themes/spacing';
import fonts from 'themes/fonts';

const verticalPaddingSmall = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    ...spacing('small', 'vertical', true),
  },
  title: {
    ...spacing('xsmall', 'horizontal', false),
    ...fonts.title,
    fontSize: 25, //<--- overwrite default values from title
  },
});
```

I rarely overwrite styles on components, because my common styles handle different styles for tables and phones, kinda like media queries on the web.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it more clear. Styled Components is a library for using CSS in React components. I edited the question to link to the library source code.